# Is there a way to increase fast healing?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, healing

I recently discovered the [*fast healer* feat](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/fast-healer/), and am curious if the amount of hit points regained stacks with that provided by the [fast healing ability](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/#Fast_Healing_Ex)? I'm wondering if in this case fast healing qualifies as either magical healing or resting.

Also, do multiple forms of fast healing stack? I've already seen on this site that it does for Legends, but I'm wondering of it's the same for Pathfinder.

Are there other ways to increase fast healing?

Comment: Are you talking about [this feat](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/fast-healer/) and how it interacts with the [Fast Healing](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/#Fast_Healing_Ex) special ability?

Comment: Yes, that's the one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ask Your GM.**

There are debates on the subject [here](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2lkdh?Fast-Healer-Fast-Healing) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Pathfinder_RPG/comments/an8voc/feat_clarification_fast_healer_and_fast_healing/) with no clear consensus, and AFAIK there's no official ruling.

It *might* depend on where your fast healing comes from.  If it's from a spell like [*infernal healing*](https://aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Infernal%20Healing), you could definitely argue that it counts as "magical healing." (Fast healing is in no way considered "resting," since it works even in the heat of combat, so you can set that part aside.) If it comes from a class ability or racial feature, however, the wording gets trickier and I personally would say it doesn't work:

> **Fast Healing:** A creature with fast healing regains hit points at an exceptional rate, usually 1 or more hit points per round, as given in the creature's entry.  Except where noted here, **fast healing is just like natural healing.** Fast healing does not restore hit points lost from starvation, thirst, or suffocation, nor does it allow a creature to regrow lost body parts.  Unless otherwise stated, it does not allow lost body parts to be reattached.  Fast healing continues to function (even at negative hit points) until a creature dies, at which point the effects of fast healing end immediately.

(Emphasis mine.)

Comment: The source of the fast healing I'm specifically thinking of is from the mutant template. The part that's throwing me off is that the fluff text for the feat says " You benefit greatly from your healing, be it from spells or natural healing." Since fast healing counts as natural healing I originally thought that it counted, but the  feat explanation only lists resting and magic as counting. The second link provided gives a decent argument to consider, so I guess I'll just leave it to the DM whether fast healing counts as resting.